# Airflow: create one-time dynamic SubDag

Tags: python, airflow

I am creating a dag that performs tasks that were pre-defined in some database. 
after the tasks are performed, I am updating their execution time until they should be performed again. the purpose of each task is basically to do sql unittesting.

what I tried to so far is

1. creating the parent main dag
2. getting the list of tasks from the database
3. for each row (task) - i'm creating subdag that contains the execution process
4. when all the subdags completes - i'm updating the exuction times of the tasks

currently it fails after the first run. the error that is shown `Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/src/dags/d06-query_validations/d06-query_validations_daily.py] list index out of range`.
please, help me figure out what is the problem

what I tried so far:

```
default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2018, 11, 25, 8, 15),
'wait_for_downstream': True,
'email': email_list,
'email_on_failure': True,
'email_on_retry': False
}


def getValidationsToRun():
    start_time = datetime.now()
    conn = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id='mysql_main', kwargs={"charset": "utf8"})
    query = ReadTextFile('/d06-query_validations/get_validations.sql')
    logging.log(logging.INFO, "Extract Query={}".format(query))
    records = conn.get_pandas_df(query)
    logging.log(logging.INFO, "Extract completed. it took: 
    {}".format(str(datetime.now() - start_time)))
    return records


def create_subdag(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name, validation):
    inner_dag = DAG(
        %s.%s' % (parent_dag_name, child_dag_name),
        default_args=default_args.copy(),
        schedule_interval='@once'
    )
    QueryValidationFlow(
        dag=inner_dag,
        validation_name=validation.validationName,
        title=validation.messageTemplate,
        query=validation.query,
        expected_result=validation.expectedResult,
        source_db=validation.source,
        emails=validation.emailRecipients.split(',')
        )
        return inner_dag


def create_subdag_operator(parent_dag, validation):
    child_dag_name = 'subdag_{}'.format(validation.validationName)
    parent_dag_name = parent_dag.dag_id
    subdag = SubDagOperator(
        task_id=child_dag_name,
        dag=parent_dag,
        subdag=create_subdag(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name, validation)
    )
    return subdag


def create_subdag_operators(parent_dag, validations):
    subdag_list = [create_subdag_operator(parent_dag, row) for index, row in validations.iterrows()]
    # chain subdag operators together
    helpers.chain(*subdag_list)
    return subdag_list


# (top-level) DAG & operators
dag = DAG(dag_id='d06-query_validations', schedule_interval='0 * * * *', 
default_args=default_args, catchup=False)

curr_validations = getValidationsToRun()

curr_validation_ids = ",".join(["'%s'" % str(validationId) for validationId in curr_validations["validationId"]])

dummy_op_start = DummyOperator(task_id='d06-op_start', dag=dag)

subdag_ops = create_subdag_operators(dag, curr_validations)

update_execution_time = MySqlOperator(
    task_id='d06-update_execution_time',
    sql=ReadTextFile('/d06- 
    query_validations/update_validations.sql').format(curr_validation_ids),
    mysql_conn_id='mysql_main',
    retries=5,
    execution_timeout=timedelta(minutes=2),
    retry_delay=60,
    dag=dag
)

dummy_op_start >> subdag_ops[0]
subdag_ops[-1] >> update_execution_time
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI everything in the immediate context of your DAG file is executed in a loop by the airflow webserver and the airflow scheduler in order to determine what's in your DAG. This happens even to python files in the DAG folder that do not produce dags. It happens also to DAG files for which the DAG has no schedule or which has been disabled in the UI or DB. It does this because any python file *might* produce a new DAG dynamically.

So this is run a lot:

```
def getValidationsToRun():
  start_time = datetime.now()
  conn = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id='mysql_main', kwargs={"charset": "utf8"})
  query = ReadTextFile('/d06-query_validations/get_validations.sql')
  logging.log(logging.INFO, "Extract Query={}".format(query))
  records = conn.get_pandas_df(query)
  logging.log(logging.INFO, "Extract completed. it took: 
  {}".format(str(datetime.now() - start_time)))
  return records
```

Which I'm sure you'd see if you're checking your scheduler's logs.

I suspect that sometimes the results are empty and so `subdag_ops[0]` is out of range.

Also

```
sql=ReadTextFile(
    '/d06-query_validations/update_validations.sql').format(curr_validation_ids),
```

indicates that you haven't read about using templated fields and parameters. It should probably be more like:

```
sql='./d06- 
query_validations/update_validations.sql',
params={'val_ids': curr_validation_ids},
```

with the sql file containing `{{ params.val_ids }}` somewhere in there.

Maybe the [Astronomer docs for templating](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/templating/) will help more than the [Airflow ones](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#macros)?